# How the child process works on its own directory?

Tags: go, process

Consider a Go program that runs another exe file:

```
command := exec.Command("C:\\myapplication.exe")
if err := command.Run(); err != nil {
}
```

And consider that myapplication.exe contains below code segment:

```
os.Create("generatedfile.txt")
```

The problem is that the generatedfile.txt is created in the directory of the parent process and not in the directory of the child process (C:\).
What should be done to transfer control to the child process in such a way that the file is created in the child process's directory without changing the string inside os.Create (i.e. generatedfile.txt)?

Comment: Contrary to a lot of other documentation it's worth the actually _read_ the documentation of Go types and functions you use. Most of the time this doesn't take long and is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [exec Cmd.Dir](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.Dir) documentation says:

> Dir specifies the working directory of the command. If Dir is the empty string, Run runs the command in the  calling process's current directory.

The application does not set the `command.Dir`, therefore the child process runs in the calling process's current directory.

To fix the problem, set `command.Dir` to the directory where you want to run the child process.

```
command := exec.Command("C:\\myapplication.exe")
command.Dir = "C:\\some\\directory"
if err := command.Run(); err != nil {
}
f, err := os.Create("generatedfile.txt")
// file is created in C:\some\directory\generatedfile.txt
```